# Serializing and deserializing geometry in three.js using toJSON and BufferGeometryLoader. Transferring geometries as string

Tags: javascript, serialization, three.js, deserialization, web-worker

**First of all - I'm a beginner in three.js and I just want to share my experience.**

My task was to convert geometry into something and transfer it to another WebWorker(you cannot transfer all objects between workers, only [structured cloneable datatypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types). So I opened documentation and tried to use .toJSON and then BufferGeometryLoader(and many other approaches).

```js
const box = new BoxBufferGeometry();
const geomJSON = box.toJSON();
const geometriesLoader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
const parsedGeom = geometriesLoader.parse(geomJSON);
const mesh = new Mesh(parsedGeom);
this.scene.add(mesh);
```

and I received this error:

[image]

Also, I tried other types of loaders, `JSON.stringify`, etc. But only packing meshes with geometries in the GLTF file and serializing it using callback seems to work(not very handy).


I asked holy Internet for help but he didn't hear me. And documentation says only:

> `.toJSON () : Object` Convert the buffer geometry to three.js JSON Object/Scene format.

**Three.js version:** 0.135.0 and 0.136.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I thought I will die, but then I accidentally found that function: `.toNonIndexed()`.

```js
const box = new BoxBufferGeometry();
const geomJSON = box.toNonIndexed().toJSON();
const geometriesLoader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
const parsedGeom = geometriesLoader.parse(geomJSON);
const mesh = new Mesh(parsedGeom);
this.scene.add(mesh);
```

I am not sure what it does, but at least it works now, and I can see my geometry after serialization. I am not sure that it doesn't cause other problems though.

*If you are more experienced in three.js, then please, give me and other **noobs** more information about this **issue** and the purpose of `.toJSON`. Thanks.*

Comment: Thank you. I also had to do `.toNonIndexed()` to get the desired result. I'm assuming its bceasue the JSON by default doesn't store indexed data.

Comment: another important thing to note here is that when you convert geometry `toNonIndexed`, the position array will have duplicate vertices, so if you want to convert the geometry back to indexed geometry then you need to use `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(parsedGeom)`. Check [this link](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/buffergeometry-toindexed/1334/10) for more details