# three.js export toJSON doesn't work with bufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a three.js application where I need to draw a shapeGeometry and then update the vertices of those shape geometry into different heights based on the Geo-location API. So I have been using below method to acheive this:

```js
const attPos = mesh.geometry.attributes.position as THREE.BufferAttribute;
let bufferPoints: number[];
for (let i = 0; i < attPos.array.length / 3; i++) {
  const pt = new Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(attPos, i).clone();
  const height = getApiHeight(pt);
  pt.setZ(height ); // set height of each point from API

  bufferPoints.push(pt.x, pt.y, pt.z + offset);
  const F32A = new Float32Array(bufferPoints);

  mesh.geometry.attributes.position = new BufferAttribute(F32A, 3);
}
```

This is working fine,but the challenge that I have is when I export the scene to JSON using `scene.toJSON()` method. the exported scene doesn't have the height information since the `.toJSON()` method doesn't include buffer attributes in the JSON output.

How to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found this method in the documentation [BufferGeometry.toJSON](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buff#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.toJSON), but that did not work either. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70788994/6908282) and it worked for me:

```js
const geomJSON = mesh.geometry.toNonIndexed().toJSON();
```

I store above json and the load it using [BufferGeometryLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/BufferGeometryLoader)

```js
const geometriesLoader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
const parsedGeom = geometriesLoader.parse(geomJSON);
const mesh = new Mesh(parsedGeom);
this.scene.add(mesh);
```