# Convert non-indexed buffer geometry to indexed

Tags: three.js

I recently had to work on a project where I had to export a scene which has buffer-geometries and load it back. But since `scene.toJSON` doesn't export buffer geometry. So I used `mesh.geometry.toNonIndexed().toJSON()` to get the JSON format of the buffer geometry and then use `geometriesLoader.parse(geomJSON)` to load it back into the scene (*which I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77292063/6908282)*).

But this caused the geometry to have more number of vertices in the position buffer that the original geometry - most probably because its a non-indexed buffer geometry.

How can I convert the non-indexed buffer geometry to an indexed geometry.

Answer (score 0):

On doing some research I found [this question](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/buffergeometry-toindexed/1334) in three.js forum which talks about the same thing.

There are 2 solutions mentioned in the forum

1. the [BufferGeometryToIndexed.js](https://github.com/Fyrestar/THREE.BufferGeometry-toIndexed/blob/master/BufferGeometryToIndexed.js) code written by Fyrestar
2. the [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices](https://BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices), which was later added to the three.js code-base.

You can use either of these 2, I used the `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices` like below:

```js
const bufferGeoJSON = mesh.geometry.toNonIndexed().toJSON(); // example variable to store non-indexed geometry

const jsonToBufferGeo = bufferGeoLoader.parse(bufferGeoJSON);
const mergedGeo = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(jsonToBufferGeo);

mesh.geometry = mergedGeo;
```